Elementor design collapses after plugin auto-update
I have enabled auto-updates for the Elementor plugin, but whenever the plugin updates automatically, the website design collapses. Each time, I have to go to the Elementor tool options and regenerate CSS & Data, which negatively impacts the user experience.
Please let me know how I can fix this issue.
Thanks
I want the plugin to automatically regenerate the CSS and data with every update, ensuring the design remains unaffected.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As far as I understand what you are saying, every time there is an update for elementor page builder plugin, all the custom-designed page's custom CSS is gone and you have to regenerate all the CSS code and add it again to make the custom design look fine?
I recommend using a third-party plugin such as Custom CSS & JS plugin to keep all your custom CSS separately so that whenever the elementor plugin is updated, you don't lose the CSS and the design stays intact.
Another way to ensure that your page layout and design are not affected and that CSS stays intact is to learn how to create a child theme in WordPress.
